# Can cmake automatically add fortran preprocessor -cpp flag?

Tags: cmake, fortran

I have some fortran sources with preprocessor instructions. I usually compile them with `ifort -cpp -DOPT1 -DOPT2 ...` in a Makefile. Now I'm trying to change to cmake, and to add these options I use `target_compile_definitions(target PUBLIC OPT1)`. But when I run the compilation, the command shows only `ifort -DOPT1 -DOPT2 ...` and therefore fails.

I've read that some compilers have this flag set by default, like gfortran:

> ```
> -cpp
> -nocpp  Enable preprocessing. The preprocessor is automatically invoked if
>         the file extension is .fpp, .FPP, .F, .FOR, .FTN, .F90, .F95, .F03
>         or .F08. Use this option to manually enable preprocessing of any 
>         kind of Fortran file.
> ```

but it looks like this is not explicitly the case for ifort:

> ```
> -cpp   Runs the Fortran preprocessor on source files prior
>        to compilation (same as the -fpp option).
> ```

Is there an option I missed in cmake to add this flag or not ? If no, what would be the proper way to add it manually with a cmake command ?

Thank you !

Comment: `add_compile_options(-cpp)` ?

Comment: You can provide target-specific compile options using `target_compile_options(target PUBLIC -cpp)`.

Comment: Ok thank you, so a priori I still need to hard-code it. I'm going to use the one with `target_` to stay "target centered".

Comment: I would caution you that there are certain obscure compilers for which -cpp is not the correct flag. I recommend checking if the compiler is intel before setting the flag, or using the try_compile command to set it only if it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you have CMake 3.18 or later, use the [`Fortran_PREPROCESS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/Fortran_PREPROCESS.html) property:

```
set_source_files_properties(
  file1.fpp file2.fpp
  PROPERTIES Fortran_PREPROCESS ON
)
```