# fortran defined macro ignored with cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I am trying to create a new macro in a Fortran file. Such file is one of many in a bigger project. It is compiled through a CMake file and gfortran.

For its simplicity I just included a simple example:

```
#define hello call

module SIO_ncDimBounds_mod

  use SIO_ncParams_mod, only: MAX_DIMLEN_NAME
  ...
  logical, parameter :: ISDEBUG = .false.

  hello  -> not recognized as Macro
```

When It is compiled it is ignored so it raises an error:

```
../soulio/src/ncDimBounds_mod.F90:34:2:

   34 |   hello
      |  1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

As far as I understand, with upper case file extension should be enough to execute the preprocessor. I also checked the '-cpp' flag is enabled. I doubled checked with verbose mode to ensure it is enabled:

```
[ 22%] Building Fortran object src/CMakeFiles/soulio_lib.dir/ncDimBounds_mod.F90.o
cd ../soulio/build/src && /usr/bin/gfortran -DENABLE_MPI -I../projects/soulio/src/soulshared_lib -I../soulio/extern/Library/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib  -ffree-form -std=f2008 -fimplicit-none -cpp -g -fbounds-check -pedantic -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -O0 -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wextra --coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -J../../lib   -c ../soulio/src/ncDimBounds_mod.F90 -o CMakeFiles/soulio_lib.dir/ncDimBounds_mod.F90.o
```

I also include the CMakeFile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(soulio)
enable_language(Fortran)

find_program(FYPP fypp)
if(NOT FYPP)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Preprocessor fypp could not be found")
endif()


# custom compiler flags
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
    set(dialect "-ffree-form -std=f2008 -fimplicit-none -cpp")
    set(debugMode "-fbounds-check -pedantic -ffpe-trap=zero,invalid,overflow,underflow -O0 -Wall -fcheck=all -fbacktrace -Wextra")
    set(optimizedMode "-ftree-vectorize" ) 
endif()
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Intel")
    set(dialect "-stand f08 -free -implicitnone")
    set(debugMode "-check bounds")
    set(optimizedMode "-O3 -xHost")
endif()
if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "PGI")
    set(dialect "-Mfreeform -Mdclchk -Mstandard -Mallocatable=03")
    set(debugMode "-C")
    set(optimizedMode "")
endif()

set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE} ${optimizedMode}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${debugMode}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${dialect}")

# Place lib and binary files
# dynamic libraries
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# static library
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib) 

# target files
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

# Have the .mod files placed in the lib folder
SET(LIB ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
SET(CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${LIB})

# include cmake modules
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
include(soulioUtils)

message(status ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# call for netcdf library
if (NOT HAS_SOULSM)
  set (NETCDF_C "YES")
  set (NETCDF_F90 "YES")
  set (NETCDF_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/include)
  set (NETCDF_INCLUDES_C ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/include)
  set (NETCDF_INCLUDES_F77 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/include)
  set (NETCDF_INCLUDES_F90 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/include)
  set (NETCDF_INCLUDES_CXX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/include)
  set (NETCDF_LIBRARIES_F77 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/lib/libnetcdff.so)
  set (NETCDF_LIBRARIES_F90 ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/lib/libnetcdff.so)
  set (NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/lib/libnetcdf.so)
  set (NETCDF_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Library/lib/libnetcdf.so)

  find_package (NetCDF REQUIRED)
endif()


if (ENABLE_MPI)
  find_package (MPI REQUIRED)
  add_definitions(-DENABLE_MPI)
endif()

message(STATUS "Run: ${MPIEXEC} ${MPIEXEC_NUMPROC_FLAG} ${MPIEXEC_MAX_NUMPROCS} ${MPIEXEC_PREFLAGS} EXECUTABLE ${MPIEXEC_POSTFLAGS} ARGS")

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  enable_testing()
  SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )

  include( cmake/CodeCoverage.cmake )
  SET(coverageMode "--coverage -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
  set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${coverageMode}")

  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()

if (NOT HAS_SOULSM)
  add_subdirectory(soulshared)
endif()
add_subdirectory(src)
```

I did a simple and isolated test with a fortran file with an uppercase extension, as expected it works.

Why is the macro not replaced with CMake? It seems to me the preprocessor it is not called.

Edit:
'hello' is changed to lowercase

Comment: In your example the define is in lowercase and the usage in upper case, what happens when both have the same case?

Comment: I edited the question to 'hello' lowercase. Still the same issue

Comment: Check if the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66742597/11697936) helps.

Comment: @NalinRanjan I tried with the same effect as detailed.

Comment: If hello is defined as call, and you are just having hello in a line on its own, then this will translate to call on its own which is an error.

Comment: You will need something like **hello fred** where fred is a defined routine.   That would translate to **call fred**

Comment: @cup you are right, by itself is an error. So I am aware of it. My point is to prove the Preprocessor is not doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

If we change the example to

```
subroutine silly()
    print *, 'It works'
    return
end subroutine silly

#define hello call

program main
    hello silly
    stop
end program main
```

and build using

```
gfortran -cpp macro.f90
```

This builds without any problems. If I just have `hello` on its own, then I get a syntax error.

First, make sure your program is valid. `call` on its own will generate an error. You need to `call` something.

Could you try building without cmake? If it works without cmake and doesn't work with cmake then it is a cmake problem. Otherwise, you just have a problem with your code.